# PHP Try/Catch exception - Parse.com SDK

Tags: php, parse-platform, exception, sdk, try-catch

I'm working on some PHP website, and I'm using the Parse.com SDK.

So, the SDK has some built-in "LogIn" function which is working fine, there is just one issue: if the login fails (bad credentials for example) it's throwing an exception, thus stopping the website from running.

Is there a way to not do that? And just show a message like "Bad credentials" or something? (I don't want to alter the default login function, I just want a way - if there is - to not stop the website from running when this exception is thrown)

Before someone asks: YES I've already consulted multiple times the documentation on the SDK. YES I've already asked it to the Parse community on their Google Group (which is inactive it seems). And finally YES I've searched about this on other forums (the whole point of posting it here, is that I didn't found it).

Thank you for helping :-)

Solid

Comment: Can you show your code.

Comment: @Jangyasatapathy, thanks for your answer. I tried to paste the relevant code here: http://pastebin.com/4FDmsGyE

Comment: Great code! I will get back to you soon with answers.

Comment: Simply do after catch echo '$error->getMessage()'

Comment: This still gets me this screen: http://imgur.com/sq6JEgz

Comment: Need to handle manually.Refer [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839173/catch-a-fatal-exception-and-continue)

Comment: I don't know how your answer is helping me, but thanks I guess. Trying to figure out what you're trying to say to me.

Comment: try/catch blocks only work for thrown exceptions (throw Exception or a subclass of Exception must be called). You cannot catch fatal errors using try/catch.You have to use register_shutdown_function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code,

```
function user_login($username, $password) {
    try {
        $user = ParseUser::logIn($username, $password);
        return $user;
    } catch (ParseException $error) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

$user = user_login($username, $password);
if($user){
    // $message = "Logged in";
    // code to show message whether user logged in 
} else {
    // $message = "Bad credentials";
    // code to show message "bad credentials"
}
```